# Flip Button Background Image Vertically

Tags: html, css, button, background-image, flip

I'm using CSS to style my button which has a background Image. I need a press effect. so I tried flopping my button vertically when it is active, as demonstrated in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/xzBaZ/10/

I'm able to Flip the image but along with the whole button. How can I only flip the background Image. ??

I have to write in another class other than `.button:active` or what?? Plaease help

Please check the Third and Fourth buttons and flip the BackgroundImage. The Firse and second buttons contain a `<img>` I do not want it to be flipped.

if this is not cross browser supported, Can you tell me how to change the background when button is active without changing the background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `active` state only for image

```
.button:active img{
    /*Vertical Flip background img*/
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    top: 1px; position: relative;
    /*-webkit-transform: translateY(1px);-moz-transform: translateY(1px);*/
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xzBaZ/12/)**

**[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/)** is the best tutorial for flipping the elements separately

http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: Did you check, the Flip is actually not working in your demo. only the  positioning is working. first please compare yours with my fiddle to see the difference in flip. and please consider the third and fourth buttons.

Comment: @KrishnaThota Yes I did. In your demo flip is flipping the text as well as image, but in my demo it is flipping only image. Is that what you need or something else??

Comment: No, you are flipping the `<img>` but I need to flip the background Image. please consider rechecking.

Comment: @KrishnaThota Check your fiddle. BG image links are not working so not able to see any images there.\

Comment: The emboss effect is due to the background images only. please check the line 43 in the fiddle Css